# rails3 + Jquery data dispay issue

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a **Rails3** application with **JQuery**. and I have the following code (I have a div with id 'new' as well)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/users/new',
    success: function(data) {
        $("#new").html( data );
    }
});
```

and in my users controller new action is as follows

```
 def new
    @user = User.new
    @sample_value = "sample value"
 end
```

But when i try to display the variable `@sample_value`  in the view it seems like its blank (doesnt have any value)

How can i pass an instance variable (@) from my controller to views

please help

my setup is as follows

- Rails 3 JQuery (CDN)
- http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js
- Linux

thanks in advance

cheers

sameera

Comment: i am developer on asp.net mvc but i can help you. you have done all right from jquery side. but Rails3 side maybe you have mistakes. does your action returns @sample_value as result? if you want to return both  @user and @sample_value variables to response, then you can create json and send it as data to jquery. and there you can parse it. but in anyway your action must return somethink

Comment: Hi @AEMLoviji, thanks a lot for the answer you are correct I haven't returned anything. I should return js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way to go is just render your data

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @sample_value = "sample value"
  render :text => @sample_value
end
```

But good practice is to hadle it as a `js` request and make a responde in your `new.js.erb` file

Comment: Hi fl00r, got it working, and implemented to return js. rails + ujs + jquery thanks a lot :D